# How do I set custom MAC address on iOS?

Tags: ios, mac-address

I want to set the MAC address of my iPhone to a specific value, how do I do that?

Comment: You most likely can't. Which problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: @nohillside I'm trying to connect to a Wi-Fi that uses captive portal and the login page is broken, so I want to change my MAC address to that of an authenticated device.

Comment: Can the authenticated device act as a hotspot for the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device is jailbroken on iOS 14 you can use MacSpoof from https://repo.anamy.gay

Source code: https://github.com/elihwyma/MacSpoof/blob/main/src/Tweak/Tweak.x

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to set the MAC address of the WiFi interface on the iPhone to a specific value without jailbreaking.